# Toggle div visibility with same name

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script to toggle a div visibility, but it only shows the first div, and not the others.

```
<div id="toggle">Toggle</div>
<div id="to_toggle">1</div>
<div id="to_toggle">2</div>
```

How to create a script for this?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: So show your script, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to use an ID more than once, thats what classes are for.

```
<div id="toggle">Toggle</div>
<div class="to_toggle">1</div>
<div class="to_toggle">2</div>
```

The javascript version:

```
document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = function(){
    var elements2toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('to_toggle');
    var current = elements2toggle[0].style.display;
    var setTo = current=='none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    var loopLength = elements2toggle.length;
    for(i=0; i<loopLength; i++){
        elements2toggle[i].style.display = setTo;
    }
};
```

And the jQuery version. As you can see, it is a lot easier to read. Don't use jQuery just for this part, check out if you can use it more broadly, it has a lot of functionality.

```
$('#toggle').on('click', function(){
    $('.to_toggle').toggle(); // now use the class to toggle
});
```

---

David asked me to benchmark (learned another website today ;)), here are the results:
http://jsperf.com/fastest-method-to-toggle-items

*Seems like using jQuery to check the current display is faster than the `.toggle()`, so I stand corrected about that (one of my comments on a answer said otherwise)*.

Comment: this could also be done with javascript but would take more lines

Comment: Then I removed that reason ;)

Comment: i am giving you down vote coz you used jquery firstly

Comment: @Ehsan: that's a little harsh, he did, after all, compensate for and correct his mistake.

Comment: For real? Thats probaly the most pointless motivation I've ever heard om SO. Just because I have you a downvote, WITH argumentation?

Comment: dear you downn voted mine on the same reason that why i provided solution with jquery, so you also provided jquery, you also deserve down vote then, simply

Comment: sorry @Martijn if you think i am harsh, i just realized you what you did

Comment: I think you should read a bit better what I wrote. It has nothing to do with jQuery-only, it's about hów you use it. Nevertheless, I used your *constructive* comment, and editted my post :)

Comment: now you have edited all your post, firstly you posted jquery as i posted

Comment: i can edit mine now, but its not worth it now, i am not doing like you, i posted what i thought i was using if i was in that case

Comment: I know, that's why I editted it... I changed it according to the commentary I got, and therefore the reason for the downvote should be reconsidered. You should know this, you've been here for a while too

Comment: I'm going to stop responding about this subject. You gave a downvote, with comment, and I fixed the 'problem', which should result in the removal of the downvote. Childish behaviour like downvoting because you got downvoted will hurt you more than me in the long run :) Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

On the grounds you never implied that jQuery should, or could, be used, I thought I'd offer a 'plain' JavaScript alternative (albeit one that'll likely only work in up-to-date browsers):

```
// extending the prototype of a basic HTMLElement, adding a named method:
HTMLElement.prototype.toggle = function (toggleClass) {
    // calling the Array.prototype.forEach method to iterate over an array/collection:
    // using the collection returned by 'document.querySelectorAll()'
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.' + toggleClass), function(a){
        // a is the DOM node over which we're currently iterating:
        a.style.display = a.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
};

// getting the element we wish to use to activate the 'toggle()' method,
// adding an event listener (listening for the 'click' event), and then
// calling an anonymous function:
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // 'this' here is the element we retrieved earlier,
    // and we call the 'toggle()' method, supplying the
    // name of the class we want to toggle:
    this.toggle('to_toggle');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zTMY4/).

References:

- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`[].prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).